# ActionBarSherlock Tabs landscape width

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Im using actionbarsherlock tab navigation and they work fine.
The only problem im having is that when going in landscape mode the tabs dont fill the whole width of the screen and are small unlike in portrait.

I been looking at styling the tabs but i cannot find the right setting to make the tabs wider.
What do I need so the tabs can fill the width on the screen in landscape

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way to do this is using a custom view. Check this out:

[Set menu items centered and full-width with ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966639/set-menu-items-centered-and-full-width-with-actionbarsherlock)